# How do you extract the date format "Month_name date, year" into separate columns of date, month and year in Pandas? For eg. "August 30, 2019"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I've seen extractions of date, month and year from data format: "DD-MM-YYYY" and the like. (Where the month is numbered rather than named)

However, I have a dataset which has date values in the format: "Month_name date, year".
Eg. "August 30, 2019".

Comment: did you try anything, for example `pd.to_datetime("August 30, 2019")`? please add a [mre] of your actual problem.

Comment: Is there a need to handle invalid inputs?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your DataFrame contains *TxtDate* column, with
date strings:

```
             TxtDate
0    August 30, 2019
1       May 12, 2020
2  February 16, 2020
```

The first step is to convert the source column to *datetime* type and save it
in a new column:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TxtDate)
```

This function is so "clever" that you can do even without explicit
format specification.

Then extract partilular date components (and save them in respective
columns):

```
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year
df['Month'] = df.Date.dt.month
df['Day'] = df.Date.dt.day
```

And the last step is to drop *Date* column (you didn't write
that you need the **whole** date):

```
df.drop(columns='Date', inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
             TxtDate  Year  Month  Day
0    August 30, 2019  2019      8   30
1       May 12, 2020  2020      5   12
2  February 16, 2020  2020      2   16
```

Maybe you should also drop *TxtDate* column (your choice).

Comment: In addition, the `errors=` argument in `pd.to_datetime()` is very handy when processing real (dirty) data. Using `errors="coerce"` will output `NaT` (missing value in Pandas) for invalid inputs instead of raising an exception.